# Plotly Dash stacked bar > 4 stacks [Python]

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a Plotly Dash stacked graph. When I have more than four different bars in my stack, the graph becomes impossible to see. Here is my code......

```
  dcc.Graph(
   figure=go.Figure(
    data=[

        go.Bar(
            x=list(df.month.unique()),
            y=df.loc[df['location'] == 'Brn'].Talks,
            name='Brn',
            marker=go.bar.Marker(
                color='#da202a',
            )
        ),

        go.Bar(
            x=list(df.month.unique()),
            y=df.loc[df['location'] == 'Wrl'].Talks,
            name='Wrl',
            marker=go.bar.Marker(
                color='#2a2a2d',
            )
        ),

        go.Bar(
            x=list(df.month.unique()),
            y=df.loc[df['location'] == 'Lpl'].Talks,
            name='Lpl',
            marker=go.bar.Marker(
                color='#c1c6c8',
            )
        ),

        go.Bar(
            x=list(df.month.unique()),
            y=df.loc[df['location'] == 'HNE'].Talks,
            name='HNE',
            marker=go.bar.Marker(
                color='#0892cb',
            )
        ),
        layout=go.Layout(
        title='Conversation Required',
        showlegend=True,
        barmode='stack',
        xaxis = dict(tickvals=df.month.unique())
        ))
```

This is my code for creating the different stacks, however, when I want to add 5 or more stacks on the bar chart everything becomes impossible to see?

[image: Graph with 4 stacks]

[image: Graph with 5 stacks or more]

Comment: can you share the code with 5 or more stacks and if possible the csv so that the issue can be replicated?

Comment: go.Bar(
            x=list(df.month.unique()),
            y=df.loc[df['location'] == 'HNS'].Talks,
            name='HNE',
            marker=go.bar.Marker(
                color='#0892cb',
            )
        ),

Answer (score 0):

Based on the format of your second chart, it seems that at least one date value in the fifth stack is very different from the rest. Perhaps the value is `NULL` or `0` and plotly is attempting to plot that date along with all the recent dates, which results in the wide x-axis. Without seeing your dataset it is hard to say, as the code seems fine.

Try restricting the x-axis range in the layout to see if that additional stack is being plotted on the three bars as a troubleshooting step.

```
layout['xaxis'].update({'range': [date_low, date_high]})
```